# Символьные вычисления (упростить математическое выражение)

Tags: python, математика

Есть вот такой пример:

```
0.88522+(x-0.2)*0.9823456+(x-0.235)(x-0.2145)*(-0.976123)
```

Необходимо преобразовать его к следующему виду (результат из `Wolfram Mathematica`):

```
0.639547 + 1.42111 x - 0.976123 x^2
```

Как можно это реализовать в `python`?

Comment: Никак. Питон предназначен не для этого.

Comment: какой язык это посчитает?

Comment: Господа, не нужно недооценивать Python и его модули ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html):

```
from sympy import simplify

from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (
        parse_expr,
        standard_transformations,
        implicit_application,
        implicit_multiplication,
        implicit_multiplication_application,
        function_exponentiation)

transformations=(standard_transformations +
                 (implicit_multiplication,
                  implicit_application,
                  function_exponentiation,
                  ))

formula = "0.88522+(x-0.2)0.9823456+(x-0.235)(x-0.2145)(-0.976123)"
expr = parse_expr(formula,transformations=transformations)
simplified_formula = simplify(expr)
print(simplified_formula)
```

---

результат:

```
-0.976123*x**2 + 1.4211128885*x + 0.6395469598775
```

---

PS [установка Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html)

Comment: у меня vs можете пожалуйста подсказать как туда подключить?

Comment: @СергейАлександров, дополнил ответ. Как устанавливать именно в VS не знаю - попробуйте задать новый SO вопрос - может кто-нибудь ответит...

Comment: y111=100  можете подсказать если я в эту формул хочу подставить переменную например так  "y111+(x-0.2)0.9823456+(x-0.235)(x-0.2145)(-0.976123)"

Comment: @СергейАлександров, ответил [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1042625/211923) :)