# как вставить переменные в simplify

Tags: python, sympy

a111=200

хочу вставить эту переменную но выходит ошибка

```
  formula = "a111+(x-0.2)0.9823456+(x-0.235)(x-0.2145)(-0.976123)"
```

from sympy import simplify

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (
        parse_expr,
        standard_transformations,
        implicit_application,
        implicit_multiplication,
        implicit_multiplication_application,
        function_exponentiation)

transformations=(standard_transformations +
                 (implicit_multiplication,
                  implicit_application,
                  function_exponentiation,
                  ))

formula = "0.88522+(x-0.2)0.9823456+(x-0.235)(x-0.2145)(-0.976123)"
expr = parse_expr(formula,transformations=transformations)
simplified_formula = simplify(expr)
print(simplified_formula)
```

Comment: Какая ошибка-то?

Comment: на каком этапе вы хотите подставлять значение в `a111` - до или после упрощения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [103]: from sympy import symbols

In [104]: a111 = symbols("a111")

In [105]: formula = "a111+(x-0.2)0.9823456+(x-0.235)(x-0.2145)(-0.976123)"

In [106]: expr = parse_expr(formula,transformations=transformations)

In [107]: simplified_formula = simplify(expr)

In [108]: simplified_formula
Out[108]: 1.0*a111 - 0.976123*x**2 + 1.4211128885*x - 0.2456730401225

In [109]: simplified_formula.subs(dict(a111=200))
Out[109]: -0.976123*x**2 + 1.4211128885*x + 199.754326959877
```

---

можно подставить значение переменной и **до** упрощения:

```
In [110]: expr = parse_expr(formula,transformations=transformations).subs({"a111":200})
#  NOTE:              --------------------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

In [111]: expr
Out[111]: 0.9823456*x - 0.976123*(x - 0.235)*(x - 0.2145) + 199.80353088

In [112]: simplify(expr)
Out[112]: -0.976123*x**2 + 1.4211128885*x + 199.754326959878
```